# How to make ngModel treat the content of an ngFor array as its data-binding object instead of a string?

Tags: html, arrays, angular, string, data-binding

How can I make ngModel treat the content of an ngFor array as its data-binding object instead of a string ? (see code examples below).
If I could do {{{{paths[i]}}}} that would be great - but it doesn't work.
I'm using angular7.

---

I have an array of paths and an object.
Both of them are getting build after some file is loaded to system, so I can't know in advance their content.

Those paths are paths of object values. For instance:

```
paths[0] = Data.persons[4].phones[1];
paths[1] = Data.persons[6].workPlace[0];
//and so on...
```

The object "Data" is also being created after the file is loaded.

I build a form and I'm trying to data bind with ngModel:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of fields_arr; let i=index; ">
  <tr>
    <td><b>{{item}}:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="paths[i]" name="name"></td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

the output of that is path represented as text:

```
<b>phone:</b> Data.persons[4].phones[1]
<b>workPlace:</b> Data.persons[6].workPlace[0]
...
```

And that's is not what I want!
I want to data-bind to the content at given path (that's inside the array).
Desired output example:

```
<b>phone:</b> 021455541
<b>workPlace:</b> Snacks Factory
....
```

I need to be able to edit those values directly, so that is why I want to data-bind.

If I perform the data-bind myself to the context of paths, it will work fine.
I've tried with files that I know their outcome, but I can't rely on that.

I've been asked to add a JSON representation of the data. That's a sample of it because the original object is massive.

```html
{
  "Data": {
    "persons": [
      {
        "fname": "John",
        "lname": "Smith",
        "phones": [
          "021112141",
          "022114441"
        ],
        "address": "John's ST",
        "workPlace": "Snakes Factory",
        "favPlayers": {
          "player": [
            {
              "name": "Curry",
              "team": "Golden States"
            },
            {
              "name": "Lebron",
              "team": "LA Lakers"
            },
            {
              "name": "Harden",
              "team": "Houston Rockets"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "fname": "James",
        "lname": "Smith",
        "phones": [
          "025841125",
          "022444584"
        ],
        "address": "James ST",
        "workPlace": "Baker",
        "favPlayers": {
          "player": [
            {
              "name": "Curry",
              "team": "Golden States"
            },
            {
              "name": "Westbrook",
              "team": "Thunder"
            },
            {
              "name": "Anthony Davis",
              "team": "New Orleans"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you represent your data in JSON format and add to the question?

Comment: Sure. the object is really massive, so its a sample of it.

Comment: Why would you do this?  This isn't at all how `ngModel` works;  you can't just treat string properties as some sort of pointer map.....

Comment: I'm building a form and I need to be able to edit it fields dynamicaly. I dont know in advance what the fields are going to be, so I need to build those paths and afterwards create the form. If i will do ngModel with the path is self - it will work fine. How can I do that, considering the path is inside an array?

Comment: why can't you bind the objects directly using json notation? ngModel will update the object if it is edited. That's the purpose of binding

Comment: If you can't rely on the source data, you can always convert that into a reliable way using the same parser that you use to build the path list in the first place..